# Does TestComplete support the use of AutomationProperties in WPF (XAML)

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, ui-automation, testcomplete

We have UI automation tests running in TestComplete and we want to use the AutomationProperties provided by [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752056.aspx).

I can not see the AutomationId property in the Object Spy of TestComplete, how do I get this property working with TestComplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, TestComplete does not provide direct access to attached properties like the AutomationId property. However, you still able to get values of these properties using a workaround described in [this official TestComplete forum thread](http://smartbear.com/forums/f81/t73357/using-automation-id-to-identify-objects).